# How do I drag cell values to other lines until a certain limit in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

There is a dataframe which a few lines has values and the followings lines are NaN filled. The number of NaN rows can varry and I need to drag the first row value to the following until the next filled row. Please find the example below.

Also there is a delimited line ('----') between different names.

```
Name ID
John 0123
NaN 0127
NaN 0163
--------
Bill 0122
NaN 0194
NaN 0125
NaN 0555
NaN 0666
```

What I want:

```
Name ID
John 0123
John 0127
John 0163
--------
Bill 0122
Bill  0194
Bill  0125
Bill  0555
Bill  0666
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `df['Name'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`